# Docker build failed for InvokeWebrequest

Tags: docker, containers, dockerfile, windows-container

I have a docker file to install sql server on windows server core. the below command fails with error

Docker Command

```
RUN Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $env:box -OutFile SQL.box ;      Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $env:exe -OutFile SQL.exe ;         Start-Process -Wait -FilePath .\SQL.exe -ArgumentList /qs, /x:setup ;         .\setup\setup.exe /q /ACTION=Install /INSTANCENAME=MSSQLSERVER /FEATURES=SQLEngine /UPDATEENABLED=0 /SQLSVCACCOUNT='NT AUTHORITY\System' /SQLSYSADMINACCOUNTS='BUILTIN\ADMINISTRATORS' /TCPENABLED=1 /NPENABLED=0 /IACCEPTSQLSERVERLICENSETERMS ;         Remove-Item -Recurse -Force SQL.exe, SQL.box, setup
```

Error Message

> Invoke-WebRequest : The remote name could not be resolved:
>   'go.microsoft.com' At line:1 char:76
>   + ... lyContinue'; Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $env:box -OutFile SQL.box ; Invok ...
>   +                  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>       + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:Htt    pWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest],
>   WebException
>       + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShe
>   ll.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand

The same docker file worked yesterday, but today it is failing continuously. Anyone has faced similar issue?

Comment: Something is broken with DNS. Try to build on different machine. Usually it's environmental issue which has nothing to do with Invoke-WebRequest. Disable firewall/AV etc

Answer (score 3):

Configure the Docker daemon by typing a json Docker daemon configuration file.
{
....
"dns": ["1.1.1.1","8.8.8.8", "8.8.4.4"],
...
}

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the problem is exactly but this worked for me:

Check out this script: https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/Virtualization-Documentation/tree/master/windows-server-container-tools/CleanupContainerHostNetworking

Save it somewhere (or clone the whole repo).
Run the cleanup command that suits your needs and restart your machine.